# Trying to rollback Firebase version to 2.X

Tags: node.js, npm, firebase, geofire, firebase-tools

I recently updated to the new Firebase 3 but unfortunately as far as I can tell it doesn't support Geofire queries at the moment which is important in my app, I've rolled everything else in my application to using firebase 2 however when I try to deploy my app to firebase hosting I get an error saying:

"Error: Unable to authorize access to project

Note: This version of the Firebase CLI is only compatible with projects upgraded
to the new Firebase Console. To access firebase.com apps, you will need to
use a previous version: npm install -g firebase-tools@^2.1"

So then I tried to run npm install -g firebase-tools@^2.1 but when I try firebase -V it still says I'm on version 3.0. I also tried running npm uninstall firebase which returned unbuild firebase@3.0.1 but if i check the firebase version it still say 3.0.1, I don't seem to be able to remove it, potentially i installed it elsewhere initially? I've run out of ideas please help!

Answer (score 8):

1. check your npm configuration

   `npm prefix -g`
2. if the path is 'undefined',

   `cd /usr/local/`
   remove the related firebase modules in bin, lib
3. remove firebase modules in npm

   `npm remove -g firebase-tools`
4. then install firebase-tools

   `npm install -g firebase-tools@<specific_version>`
5. alias setting for firebase, if you need.

Answer (score 2):

There was no issue with firebase it was with my NPM configuration and the $PATH wasn't correct. It could not save any applications globally not sure how it became changed.

I had to run:

```
npm config get prefix
```

Discovered that it wasn't:

```
/usr/local
```

then ran:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
```

This allowed me to install firebase 2.1 globally:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@^2.1
```