# UNAUTHENTICATED error in firebase firestore https callable cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Recently I added a couple of new callable firebase cloud functions to my mobile app. The thins is, once I deployed and tested my functions I was not able to invoke them failing with an **UNAUTHENTICATED** error. I re-deployed all my functions and still, the old ones can be invoked while the new one failed with UNAUTHENTICATED. I did some research and people were talking about the version of the Node. I upgraded the Node version but it did not work out. I upgraded the firebase-functions version and the firebase-admin version. No luck.

I tried to browse to the URL of one of the older callable cloud functions that I have deployed before and it was ok. Then I tried to browse to a newly deployed https callable firebase cloud function. I saw this message in my browser:

**Your client does not have permission to get URL /*function_name* from this server.**

Any ideas what is going on here?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, here is what I found.

According to this page: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/managing-access-iam#allowing_unauthenticated_function_invocation

> As of January 15, 2020, HTTP functions require authentication by
>   default. You can specify whether a function allows unauthenticated
>   invocation at or after deployment.

Here is what you do:

1- Browse to the link above

2- Find "Viewing users" section and click on the "Go to Google Cloud Console" button.

[image]

3- On the screen that opens, you will see a list of your deployed cloud functions. 
Select the one that is throwing the **UNAUTHENTICATED** error.

Click the Add Member button that appears on the right pane.

[image]

4- Select Cloud Functions Invoker role

[image]

5- Type allusers inside the "New Members" box. Select allUsers or allAuthenticatedUsers (Try with both to see which one works for you)

[image]

6- Hit "Save"

You should be able to invoke your firebase https callable cloud function now, and the UNAUTHENTICATED error should be gone.

Comment: What if we only want an app to access to the call?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem and what worked for me, was as simple as changing the function's name in the file (and of course where it was called) and redeploying it, which automatically deleted the first one.

EDIT #1: I've just had the same problem again and this time, I didn't rename the function. I only deleted the function manually inside firebase and then I redeployed it. It also works.

EDIT #2: Once again I had the same problem. However, this time I couldn't fix it with the alternatives above. I had upgraded my firebase-tools and something on this new version (10.3.1) was conflicting. Until I figure out what is the problem, I just downgraded firebase-tools (following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57262942/14608654) to version 10.2.2 and the error vanished.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I write wrong function name in my Flutter app

```
final callable = _functions.httpsCallable('wrong function name in here');
```